# Android JNI print int64_t to file

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, int64

I am trying to use JNI code to print Android sensor timestamps to a file.

The timestamps are [defined as](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/struct_a_sensor_event.html) `int64_t`.

The line to print the timestamp is:

```
fout<<timestamp<<std::endl;
```

Where fout is an open file stream in output mode.

When I try to compile, the following error results:

> ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream >}' and 'int64_t {aka long long int}')   XXX.cpp /YYY/jni    line ZZZ    C/C++ Problem

I thought I would make an MWE for this using standard C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main(){
  int64_t a;
  std::cin>>a;
  std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
}
```

But this compiles without an issue, which makes me think the problem is somehow in the way Eclipse compiles the code.

I am inside Eclipse 3.8.1. My default compiler is GCC 4.9.2.

Comment: The compiler knows that a=42. Try to store a timestamp there.

Comment: Or try to store there this integer

Comment: @18446744073709551615: I've modified the code so that it takes a user input, preventing the compiler from optimizing on the constant.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going into `jni/Application.mk` and using this line:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
```

instead of this line:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS+=-std=c++11.
```

Some have conjectured that the problem is due to different mappings of `long long int` in stlport.